# Background-Image disappears after the page load in IE8

Tags: html, css, image, internet-explorer-8

Here is the site: http://www.plugandsave.ca.

After the page load, the background image disappear in IE8 but works will in Firefox and chrome. I've done editing the code in the CSS and still got the same issue.
Any help would be very much appreciated. thanks much!

Comment: jQuery AND mootools? Yikes man.  I was looking at your source, try taking off the IE PNG fix and see if it still does it. You don't even need that image background... use a color!

Answer (score 0):

You can try and set your background to both the HTML selector and the BODY selector witch solved me trouble sometimes and you can use it to set two diferent backgrounds without using a bunch of div's, or much easier just set a fixed color that could solve your problem as well.